# Logical error from std string find method and count algorithm

Tags: c++, stl, std

When I was about to solve a project euler problem in C++, this was some of the experimentation code I made. It produced a quite unexpected result, so I solved it in an other programming language. But I really want to understand why this error occured. The part one of the code executes as expected, it does not print AAAA. But in part two, the logically equivalent code (the if statement) executes when the variable s is AAAA. And I have no idea why. I hope I made my problem clear, every answer given is highly appreciated! Thanks :)

Note: i'm using count from `<algorithm>`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main (int argc, char** argv) {
  string alt = "LOA";

  // CODE PART 1
  string stringToFind = "AAA";

  string df = "AAAA";

  if (df.find(stringToFind) == string::npos && count(df.begin(), df.end(), 'L') <= 1) {
    cout << df; // this does not print AAAA
  }

  /* CODE PART 2:
    this was an attempt to print out every four length string combination
    of the characters L, O, A where strings with three A's in a row and
    more than one L were excluded.
  */
  for (size_t i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    char c1 = alt[i];
    for (size_t iT = 0; iT < 3; iT++) {
      char c2 = alt[iT];
      for (size_t itr = 0; itr < 3; itr++) {
        char c3 = alt[itr];
        for (size_t itrI = 0; itrI < 3; itrI++) {
          char c4 = alt[itrI];
          string s = string(&c1)+string(&c2)+string(&c3)+string(&c4);

          if (s.find(stringToFind) == string::npos && count(s.begin(), s.end(), 'L') <= 1) {
            cout << s << endl; // this however, does print out AAAA
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Instead of checking if string::find == -1, try checking for string::find == string::npos. It's possible that in once case, the -1 is being interpreted as a size_t, and in int in the other, which would explain the strange behavior. See for details: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/

Comment: @PunDefeated tried that earlier, same result. Thanks for your suggestion though. :)

Comment: The code you have shown us won't compile.  Can you provide an MCVE showing the problem?  (Although it would be easier to read if you wrote: `const char[3] alt = "LOA"; for (char c1 : alt) for (char c2:alt) ...`

Comment: std::count from <algorithm>?

Comment: Correct. std::count from <algorithm>. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: ... which is why an MCVE is so useful.

Comment: I'll update the question with the whole .cpp file, I've never used MCVE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have written

```
          string s = string(&c1)+string(&c2)+string(&c3)+string(&c4);
```

You meant:

```
          string s = string(1,c1)+string(1,c2)+string(1,c3)+string(1,c4);
```

or

```
          string s = string(&c1,1)+string(&c2,1)+string(&c3,1)+string(&c4,1);
```

In your code, you have invoked the string constructor which takes a pointer to a nul-terminated array of char, but you given it a pointer to a single char.  That's going to invoke all sorts of undefined behaviour.

Either invoke the constructor that takes a a counter + a single char or, the one which takes a pointer and a count, and you can tell it there is exactly one character at that address.

**Edit** There is no constructor which takes a single char.  You have to give it a count + char.  Which means it's not so pretty.

Comment: Thank you so much. I got the right result with your last line. Dumb error though, but thanks!

Comment: Oh please.  Use the middle form.

Comment: Gives me an error. But this was a mock code for my problem anyway, beauty doesn't matter :)

Comment: That's because I'm a moron, and forgot to actually check the spec.  The constructor that takes a char also needs a count.  I'll edit.